# How can I append a new list to an existing list?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to add a new list to my original list of lists, aka grid, and here is my code,

```
board = [
    [" "," ","1"," "],
    [" "," ","1"," "],
    ["1","1"," "," "],
    ["1"," "," ","1"]]
def total1count(board: list):
    t = []
    for x in board:
        t.append(x.count("1"))
    return sum(t)
s = (list("1"*total1count(board)))
print(board.extend(s))
```

However, when I run the code, the output returns `None`... why is that??

Comment: Use `list1.extend(list2)`.

Comment: `extend` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return it. Do `print(board)` after `board.extend(s)`

Comment: I think I'm using that right? my print statement is formatted the way that u said it should and my output returns 'None'

Comment: @Barmar oh okay thx

Comment: You can concatenate lists using `+` operator

Answer (score 1):

**Array.extend(Array2)** did not return anything (means *none*) that's why the output is `none`.
if you want to print board you need to run `board.extend(s)` first than print `board`

```
board = [
[" "," ","1"," "],
[" "," ","1"," "],
["1","1"," "," "],
["1"," "," ","1"]]
def total1count(board: list):
    t = []
    for x in board:
        t.append(x.count("1"))
    return sum(t)
s = (list("1"*total1count(board)))
board.extend(s)
print(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend just modifies the list, you cant print it.

```
board.extend(s)
print(board)
```